# how to activate color functionality on product page in drupal-commerce

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, commerce-kickstart

Commerce kickstart drupal site,it show new product on color selection.
On my local it's working fine but on staging site it show nothing, no error and nothing.
i have activated color, stylizer,colorbox modules but no change.
I couldn't figure out what exact cause of this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

commerce_kickstart modules development with jquery1.5. and for our latest site development we use jquery1.10 or above.
But there are so many method which has deprecated with new method. for example live method with on 
method.http://api.jquery.com/live/
TO make it workable, need to change deprecated method otherwise use jquery1.8
I found jquery1.8 is working for both commerce modules and latest bootstrap themes.